# I am redirecting in dashboard when perform save product in magento2.4.5

Tags: admin-controller, magento2.4.5

I have increased max_input_vars size very big still i am getting 'Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.' , when product save in backend.

Even i am doing save any thing in backend i am redirecting in dashboard.

I have upgraded from 2.4.4 to 2.4.5.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few potential solutions to the issue you are facing:

1. Clear the Magento cache - this can help resolve issues with invalid form keys.
2. Check if the form key validation is enabled in the Magento configuration. If it is, try disabling it and see if the issue is resolved.
3. Verify that the correct permissions are set for the var/ directory in your Magento installation. The web user should have read/write permissions to this directory.
4. Check if the PHP version being used by Magento 2.4.5 is compatible with your server environment. It's possible that some PHP settings are not properly configured or there are compatibility issues.
5. Try disabling any third-party extensions that may be causing conflicts with the Magento backend. You can disable them one by one to isolate the issue.
6. Verify that the upgrade from Magento 2.4.4 to 2.4.5 was completed successfully and all required steps were followed, such as updating the database schema and data.

I hope that the information and assistance I have provided have been helpful to you.